# Well tested C/C++ lock free queue?

Tags: c++, c, queue, lock-free

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a production ready lock-free queue or hash implementation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164023/is-there-a-production-ready-lock-free-queue-or-hash-implementation-in-c)

I am looking for a well-tested, publicly available C/C++ implementation of a lock free queue.

I need at least multiple-producers/single-consumer functionality. Multiple-consumers is even better, if exists.

I'm targetting VC's `_Interlocked...` intrinsics, though anything which is straight forward to port would be fine.

Could anyone give any pointers?

Comment: The TBB library has some lock-free containers (although I can't remember whether it comes with a queue): http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

Comment: TBB has a concurrent_queue, though the docs only state that it's thread safe without mentioning lock-freeness. Anyway, TBB's license is problematic (GPL/Commercial).

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164023/is-there-a-production-ready-lock-free-queue-or-hash-implementation-in-c

Comment: Qt allows this, last time I checked. It comes with a whole whack of other stuff though (practically a whole language extension by the time QMake is done).

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok to go down that route, there's always the Windows thread pool.