# How do I know if a boost thread is done?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using boost::thread to process messages in a queue.
When a first message comes I start a message processing thread.
When a second message comes I check if the message processing thread is done.

if it is done I start a new one
if it is not done I don nothing.

How do I know if the thread is done ? I tried with joinable() but it is not working, as when the thread is done, it is still joinable.

I also tried to interrupt the process at once, and add an interruption point at the end of my thread, but it did not work.

Thanks

**EDIT :**

I would like to have my thread sleep for an undetermined time, and wake up when a signal is triggered.

The mean to do it is boost::condition_variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spawning a new thread for each incoming message is very inefficient. You should check out the [Thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern).

EDIT:

Sorry, jules, I misread your question. I recommend you take a look at the [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) pattern. Check out this [article](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) on how to roll your own blocking queue using boost condition variables. Intel's [Thread Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) also has a blocking queue implementation.

Check out this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164023) about existing lock-free queue implementations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My idea is to have only one processing thread. When it is done processing, I would like it to sleep, and to be able to wake it up as soon as a new message comes. Do you know how to do that with boost ?

Comment: You'll want a producer-consumer queue. See my addendum above.

Comment: I understand well the producer-consumer pattern. What I need is a way to wake up a thread on an event (when the buffer is not empty any more). I don't know what are the means to do this.

Comment: The link to the article I posted in my answer shows how to use a Boost condition variable to wait for an event (queue not empty). You may also want to check out Boost's documentation here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you should use the join() method to wait the end of a thread execution. You can use it with a timeout with timed_join().

You can interrupt threads with interrupt(). In this case, inside the thread an exception will occur if the execution reaches an interruption point ( a boost::this_thread::sleep() or boost::this_thread::interruption_point() ). You catch the exception inside the thread and you can then close it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking get_id() with boost::this_thread::get_id(). If they match the thread does not exist. But that will only happen if you have exited the thread.

Comment: The thread IDs are always different even when the thread is done.
How can I exit the thread ?

Comment: By exit the thread I just mean it should come to the point where the thread stops and return. But I guess joinable() do the same thing.